# Maximize window from the Main function?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, maximize

I have used a mutex to run a single instance program, and now I want the window to become maximized if it is currently minimized when the user reopens the application.

Here is the code I currently have in my Program.cs file:

```
static class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        bool Ok = true;
        string ProductName = Application.ProductName;
        Mutex m = new Mutex(true, ProductName, out Ok);
        if (!Ok)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process[] p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(ProductName);
            SetForegroundWindow(p[0].MainWindowHandle);

    }
    else
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());

    }
}
```

Comment: May I suggest that *restoring* the window (that is, un-minimize) makes more sense than *maximizing* it.

Comment: @romkyns: Agreed, definitely. `SW_SHOW` is the way to do that, as I mentioned at the bottom of my answer. That will restore the window to its previous state before being minimized, whether that was a standard window or a maximized window.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the [`ShowWindow` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548.aspx) and the `SW_MAXIMIZE` flag.

In C#, the P/Invoke declaration would look like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

private const int SW_MAXIMIZE = 3;
```

Add it to your code here:

```
if (!Ok)
{
   Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProductName);
   SetForegroundWindow(p[0].MainWindowHandle);
   ShowWindow(p[0].MainWindowHandle, SW_MAXIMIZE);
}
```

If you actually want to test whether the window is minimized first before you maximize it, you can use the old-school [`IsIconic` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633527.aspx):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);

// [...]

if (!Ok)
{
   Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProductName);
   IntPtr hwndMain= p[0].MainWindowHandle;
   SetForegroundWindow(hwndMain);

   if (IsIconic(hwndMain))
   {
      ShowWindow(hwndMain, SW_MAXIMIZE);
   }
}
```

If you just want to activate the window (rather than maximize it), use the `SW_SHOW` value (`5`) instead of `SW_MAXIMIZE`. This will restore it to its previous state, before it was minimized.

Comment: great , thats work .just Fix it in your Answer [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]

Comment: @moslem: Okay, done. Everyone forgets a closing brace every once in a while. Can you tell I'm used to writing code in an IDE?

Comment: **SW_SHOW** or value (5) doesn't work for me - nothing happends to minimized window (tested on **Win XP SP3** and **Win 7 SP1**). **SW_RESTORE** or value (9) worked for me and to my mind it's correct choice according to [**MSDN description**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548.aspx)

Comment: @bairog That's correct. You have to pick the right flag for what you want to do. `SW_SHOW` will not restore or maximize a minimized window. You need `SW_RESTORE` or `SW_MAXIMIZE` for that. The documentation is a good place to look, this answer just gets you started. It was composed specifically for the original question being asked.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to suggest a solution that is purely .NET (i.e. without OS dependency).

**Program.cs**

```
static class Program
{
    private static volatile bool _exitProcess;

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        bool createdNew;
        var showMeEventHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "MyApp.ShowMe", out createdNew);

        if (createdNew)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var form = new Form1();
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (!_exitProcess)
                {
                    showMeEventHandle.WaitOne(-1);
                    if (!_exitProcess)
                    {
                        if (form.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            form.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)form.BringFormToFront);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            form.BringFormToFront();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).Start();

            Application.Run(form);
        }

        _exitProcess = true;
        showMeEventHandle.Set();

        showMeEventHandle.Close();
    }
}
```

**ExtMethods.cs**

```
public static class ExtMethods
{
    public static void BringFormToFront(this Form form)
    {
        form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        form.ShowInTaskbar = true;
        form.Show();
        form.Activate();
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.BringFormToFront();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            ShowInTaskbar = false;
            Hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant and so much better than the DLL solution.