# FindWindow and SetForegroundWindow alternatives?

Tags: c#, .net, process

I am searching for alternatives to the old `User32.dll` version of switching to a different application with `FindWindow()` and `SetForegroundWindow()`.

I did find an alternative to the first with the usage of `Process.GetProcessesByName()` but I do not see the corresponding method to switch (set active/foreground) to that application.

Is there a way of doing that without using the *old* way with the `User32.dll`?

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**

I accepted the answer of @Sorceri although it is not the answer I was looking for.

Comment: What's wrong with using `SetForegroundWindow`?  The Windows OS keeps track of the foreground window in the Win32 subsystem, so however you do it is just going to be P/Invoking to `user32.dll` anyway.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk: Or at least, we assume that safely... :)

Comment: On the Windows Desktop I have to use `user32.dll` on Windows CE I have to use `coredll.dll`. So using a `DLLImport` always shows that you add static dependency which is wrong.

Comment: If you need to switch to YOUR application this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32322918/463464

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Answer: No.

But, to help the next wonderer looking to find a window and activate it from C# here's what you have to do:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

void ActivateApp(string processName)
{
    Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);

    // Activate the first application we find with this name
    if (p.Count() > 0)
        SetForegroundWindow(p[0].MainWindowHandle);
}
```

To bring notepad to the front, for example, you would call:

```
ActivateApp("notepad");
```

---

As a side note - for those of you who are trying to bring a window *within your application* to the foreground just call the [Activate() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.activate.aspx).

Comment: So after I use this method to bring up the desired process, could I feasibly use SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}"); with no qualms, provided my application actually responds to the keystrokes?

Comment: The documentation on SendWait suggests you can - let us know if it works!

Comment: I've tried it and the weird thing is that it works SOMETIMES, which I find really strange for machines. The problem is always computers do what we tell them to, not necessarily what we want. I may have to ask a brand new question.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`SetActiveWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646311%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as an alternative to `SetForeGroundWindow`. I'd say you should go through all the [Windows Manipulation Api Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and see if there's something you're missing out.

Also, note that you can obtain the handle of the `System.Diagnostics.Process` object via the `Process.Handle` property.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to SetForeGroundWindow is VisualBasic's AppActivate

Call it like this

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.AppActivate("WindowTitle")
```

Just because it is in the VisualBasic namespace doesn't mean you can't use it in C#.

Full Documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x57y7863(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.Diagnostics.Process Object` for a FindWindow equivalent.  There currently is no equivalent for SetForegroundWindow.  You will want use Pinvoke with SetForgroundWindow.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Comment: Which means I still have to deal with user32.dll after all? It does sound somehow weird that there is no alternative ...