# Perform Ctrl-C on specific window without focusing it

Tags: c#, c++, keyboard-events, sendmessage

I have an application to which I want to send the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> keys combination. I am trying with `SendMesssage`, but I know that the application checks for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> combination using `GetKeyState` and `GetAsyncKeyState` so `SendMessage` is pretty useless... How can I send the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> combination to this window **without calling** `SetForegroundWindow(hWnd)`? I need a solution which works without focusing/bringing to front the window.

I am temporarily using this code (but requires focus):

```
SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
SendKeys.SendWait("^(c)");
```

I am using C#, but C++ code is ok.

Comment: I believe this question has already been answered.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512373/findwindow-and-setforegroundwindow-alternatives

Comment: @barrypicker I need a solution which works without focusing/bringing to front the window.

Comment: @Darxis Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813086/can-i-send-a-ctrl-c-sigint-to-an-application-on-windows

Comment: @PeterL. I don't want to terminate the app by using Ctrl-C. I want to send a Ctrl-C on a window handle, which then copy something to clipboard. WM_COPY and other messages don't work as the app checks by GetKeyState

Comment: `SendMessage` with some `WM_KEY*`s?

Comment: @chris GetKeyState doesn't work with SendMessage

Comment: @Darxis, Oh, I see. Are you *sure* the app checks like that? It doesn't seem too normal (why activate a copy when your window isn't active). If it was truly using `GetKeyState`, it should detect a simple `SendInput`.

Comment: @chris Yes I'am sure this app check by GetKeyState, I used a debugger, I am 100% sure. I just want to automize the Copy command. I read about SendInput, but it requires a focus on the window.

Comment: `GetKeyState` doesn't require your window to be focused, though. That's why sending it just like a user pressing it should work if the app is using `GetKeyState`.

Comment: @chris Yes, but SendMessage doesn't trigger GeyKeyState. If I were to use SendInput which will probably work, I would have to focus the window first before using SendInput. SendInput cannot take as a parameter a window handle.

Comment: I just tried having a thread that waits for the space key to be pressed with a looped `GetAsyncKeyState` (async because I have no message loop, but almost the same thing). My main thread waits three seconds and uses `SendInput` to send a space. My other thread definitely catches it when the window isn't focused.

Comment: @chris Yes, you're right, my mistake. So I have to Return into my debugger because with SendInput when the window is not focused, it doesn't work

Comment: I also would like to send the Ctrl-C ONLY to this application, it shouldn't be visible to other windows like SendMessage do.

Comment: And what is strange, the app reacts to SendMessage with WM_RBUTTONDOWN, WM_RBUTTONUP, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONUP...

Comment: Without activating that app or a window of your own, something else most likely has to get those keystrokes. I don't think it's possible to set off `GetKeyState` without doing that.

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago, back when I was doing Sys Admin automation.. I used AutoIT.  It's been a long time, but if you don't mind picking up their .dll...

This is the method I'd use.. it mentions you can send directly to a window/control without focus.. in some cases you can't..

[AutoIT ControlSend Method](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlSend.htm)

Comment: Hmm, haven't tried it, I will try and let know if it works :)