# Bring Word Application to Front

Tags: c#, office-interop

I programmatically create a Word document and ask the user if he want's to display the document right now.

In order to bring the document to front I minimize and maximize the document. The document comes to front of screen but in an 'impolite' way: you can see it gets minimized and maximized.

Any idea how to 'educate' it?

```
wordApp.Visible = true;//objApp is the word application defined in my application
//minimizing and maximizing bring the Word application to front
wordApp.WindowState=WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMinimize;
wordApp.WindowState=WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMaximize;
wordApp.Activate();
```

Answer (score 10):

I found that activating both the Doc and the App brought word to the front, at least it did for me.

```
oDoc.Activate();
oWordApp.Activate();
```

Comment: might want to add:
oDoc.ActiveWindow.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize in case the window has been minimized, you want to maximize the doc and not the application

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the Minimize and Maximize and use `wordApp.Show()` does that help resolve your issue?  Every time I display a new application I use `.Show` not `.Activate`.  Hope that helps.

Comment: There is no `.Show` in `Office.Interop.Word.Application`.

Answer (score 0):

If the above does not work, you could use Win32 API [`SetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512373/findwindow-and-setforegroundwindow-alternatives).