# Assign a Button to a keypress

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, autohotkey

I have a script that is running in the background, I am making a GUI that will be need to be able to trigger the shortcut click, for example <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

Is there a way to put the input of the above keys into a `button_click` action so the button triggers the script command?

Answer (score 0):

This article will probably help you out:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839201

Also, there is the SendKeys.Send method. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx)

Sounds like you also need to use FindWindow or SetForegroundWindow. To use these you will need to reference user32.dll in the System32 folder. ([FindWindow and SetForegroundWindow alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512373/findwindow-and-setforegroundwindow-alternatives)).

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this is to verify using keypreview, i need a keypress action, as the article only verifies that a key is pressed and not to trigger the key press

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx

Comment: thank you, i have chjecked that and seems like the command

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{^}+({+}+({ESC})");


        }
Not triggering the command?

Comment: I believe the SendKeys.Send method only sends the keys to the current application. I'm assuming you need to send the keys to your background application?

Comment: Try using FindWindow or SetForegroundWindow.

Comment: I believe you will need to add User32.dll to your References.

Comment: do i find that on the internet or within the system files?

Comment: It should be in C:\Windows\System32