# how to use sendkey.send method in my C# windows form application?

Tags: c#, winforms

i have writen this code in my app and I want use SendKeys.send("^v") to send ctrl+v key to another apps, but when i execute the app it said:**SendKeys cannot run inside this application because the application is not handling Windows messages.  Either change the application to handle messages, or use the SendKeys.SendWait method.**
actually this app is a windows background app for converting text in case of keyboard layout mistake by user by pressing a global key.
i don't want user copy text by pressing ctrl+c and past with ctrl+v, I want this actions done by app after pressing a globalkey, the only work that user must to do it just select a text for converting. 
this is my code:
any help?

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]   
    public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
    public static void assign()
    {
        var HotKeyManager = new HotkeyManager();
        string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\\1.dat");
        if (s == "")
            MessageBox.Show("Please go to the setting menu and assign a shortcut keys for EN to Fa.");
        else
        {
            int c = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (s[i] == 'c')
                    c += Constants.CTRL;
                if (s[i] == 'a')
                    c += Constants.ALT;
                if (s[i] == 's')
                    c += Constants.SHIFT;
            }
            RegisterHotKey(HotKeyManager.Handle, 123, c, s[s.Length - 1]);
        }
    }
    public static void assign2()
    {
        var HotKeyManager = new HotkeyManager();           
        string a = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\\2.dat");
        if (a == "")
            MessageBox.Show("Please go to the setting menu and assign a shortcut keys for Fa to En.");
        else
        {
            int x = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (a[i] == 'c')
                    x += Constants.CTRL;
                if (a[i] == 'a')
                    x += Constants.ALT;
                if (a[i] == 's')
                    x += Constants.SHIFT;
            }
            RegisterHotKey(HotKeyManager.Handle, 234, x, a[a.Length - 1]);
        }
    }
    public static string FaToEn(string[] t)
    {
        string s = "";
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < t.Length; i++)
            switch (t[i])
            {
                case "ض":
                    {
                        s += "q";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ص":
                    {
                        s += "w";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ث":
                    {
                        s += "e";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ق":
                    {
                        s += "r";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ف":
                    {
                        s += "t";
                        break;
                    }
                case "غ":
                    {
                        s += "y";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ع":
                    {
                        s += "u";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ه":
                    {
                        s += "i";
                        break;
                    }
                case "خ":
                    {
                        s += "o";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ح":
                    {
                        s += "p";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ج":
                    {
                        s += "[";
                        break;
                    }
                case "چ":
                    {
                        s += "]";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ش":
                    {
                        s += "a";
                        break;
                    }
                case "س":
                    {
                        s += "s";
                        break;
                    }
                case "پ":
                    {
                        s += @"\";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ی":
                    {
                        s += "d";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ب":
                    {
                        s += "f";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ل":
                    {
                        s += "g";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ا":
                    {
                        s += "h";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ت":
                    {
                        s += "j";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ن":
                    {
                        s += "k";
                        break;
                    }
                case "آ":
                    {
                        s += "H";
                        break;
                    }
                case "م":
                    {
                        s += "l";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ک":
                    {
                        s += ";";
                        break;
                    }
                case "گ":
                    {
                        s += "'";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ظ":
                    {
                        s += "z";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ط":
                    {
                        s += "x";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ز":
                    {
                        s += "c";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ژ":
                    {
                        s += "C";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ر":
                    {
                        s += "v";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ذ":
                    {
                        s += "b";
                        break;
                    }
                case "د":
                    {
                        s += "n";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ئ":
                    {
                        s += "m";
                        break;
                    }
                case "و":
                    {
                        s += ",";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ً":
                    {
                        s += "Q";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ٌ":
                    {
                        s += "W";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ٍ":
                    {
                        s += "E";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ريال":
                    {
                        s += "R";
                        break;
                    }
                case "،":
                    {
                        s += "T";
                        break;
                    }
                case "؛":
                    {
                        s += "Y";
                        break;
                    }
                case ",":
                    {
                        s += "U";
                        break;
                    }
                case "]":
                    {
                        s += "I";
                        break;
                    }
                case "[":
                    {
                        s += "O";
                        break;
                    }
                case @"\":
                    {
                        s += "P";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ۀ":
                    {
                        s += "G";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ـ":
                    {
                        s += "J";
                        break;
                    }
                case "«":
                    {
                        s += "K";
                        break;
                    }
                case "»":
                    {
                        s += "L";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ة":
                    {
                        s += "Z";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ي":
                    {
                        s += "X";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ؤ":
                    {
                        s += "V";
                        break;
                    }
                case "إ":
                    {
                        s += "B";
                        break;
                    }
                case "أ":
                    {
                        s += "N";
                        break;
                    }
                case "ء":
                    {
                        s += "M";
                        break;
                    }
                case "؟":
                    {
                        s += "?";
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        s += t[i];
                        break;
                    }
            }
        return s;
    }
    public static string EnToFa(string[] t)
    {
        string s = "";
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < t.Length; i++)
            switch (t[i])
            {
                case "q":
                    {
                        s += "ض";
                        break;
                    }
                case "w":
                    {
                        s += "ص";
                        break;
                    }
                case "e":
                    {
                        s += "ث";
                        break;
                    }
                case "r":
                    {
                        s += "ق";
                        break;
                    }
                case "t":
                    {
                        s += "ف";
                        break;
                    }
                case "y":
                    {
                        s += "غ";
                        break;
                    }
                case "u":
                    {
                        s += "ع";
                        break;
                    }
                case "i":
                    {
                        s += "ه";
                        break;
                    }
                case "o":
                    {
                        s += "خ";
                        break;
                    }
                case "p":
                    {
                        s += "ح";
                        break;
                    }
                case "[":
                    {
                        s += "ج";
                        break;
                    }
                case "]":
                    {
                        s += "چ";
                        break;
                    }
                case "a":
                    {
                        s += "ش";
                        break;
                    }
                case "s":
                    {
                        s += "س";
                        break;
                    }
                case @"\":
                    {
                        s += "پ";
                        break;
                    }
                case "d":
                    {
                        s += "ی";
                        break;
                    }
                case "f":
                    {
                        s += "ب";
                        break;
                    }
                case "g":
                    {
                        s += "ل";
                        break;
                    }
                case "h":
                    {
                        s += "ا";
                        break;
                    }
                case "j":
                    {
                        s += "ت";
                        break;
                    }
                case "k":
                    {
                        s += "ن";
                        break;
                    }
                case "H":
                    {
                        s += "آ";
                        break;
                    }
                case "l":
                    {
                        s += "م";
                        break;
                    }
                case ";":
                    {
                        s += "ک";
                        break;
                    }
                case "'":
                    {
                        s += "گ";
                        break;
                    }
                case "z":
                    {
                        s += "ظ";
                        break;
                    }
                case "x":
                    {
                        s += "ط";
                        break;
                    }
                case "c":
                    {
                        s += "ز";
                        break;
                    }
                case "C":
                    {
                        s += "ژ";
                        break;
                    }
                case "v":
                    {
                        s += "ر";
                        break;
                    }
                case "b":
                    {
                        s += "ذ";
                        break;
                    }
                case "n":
                    {
                        s += "د";
                        break;
                    }
                case "m":
                    {
                        s += "ئ";
                        break;
                    }
                case ",":
                    {
                        s += "و";
                        break;
                    }
                case "Q":
                    {
                        s += "ً";
                        break;
                    }
                case "W":
                    {
                        s += "ٌ";
                        break;
                    }
                case "E":
                    {
                        s += "ٍ";
                        break;
                    }
                case "R":
                    {
                        s += "ريال";
                        break;
                    }
                case "T":
                    {
                        s += "،";
                        break;
                    }
                case "Y":
                    {
                        s += "؛";
                        break;
                    }
                case "U":
                    {
                        s += ",";
                        break;
                    }
                case "I":
                    {
                        s += "]";
                        break;
                    }
                case "O":
                    {
                        s += "[";
                        break;
                    }
                case "P":
                    {
                        s += @"\";
                        break;
                    }
                case "{":
                    {
                        s += "}";
                        break;
                    }
                case "A":
                    {
                        s += "َ";
                        break;
                    }
                case "S":
                    {
                        s += "ُ";
                        break;
                    }
                case "D":
                    {
                        s += "ِ";
                        break;
                    }
                case "F":
                    {
                        s += "ّ";
                        break;
                    }
                case "G":
                    {
                        s += "ۀ";
                        break;
                    }
                case "J":
                    {
                        s += "ـ";
                        break;
                    }
                case "K":
                    {
                        s += "«";
                        break;
                    }
                case "L":
                    {
                        s += "»";
                        break;
                    }
                case "Z":
                    {
                        s += "ة";
                        break;
                    }
                case "X":
                    {
                        s += "ي";
                        break;
                    }
                case "V":
                    {
                        s += "ؤ";
                        break;
                    }
                case "B":
                    {
                        s += "إ";
                        break;
                    }
                case "N":
                    {
                        s += "أ";
                        break;
                    }
                case "M":
                    {
                        s += "ء";
                        break;
                    }
                case "?":
                    {
                        s += "؟";
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        s += t[i];
                        break;
                    }
            }
        return s;
    }

    public sealed class HotkeyManager : NativeWindow, IDisposable
    {
        public HotkeyManager()
        {
            CreateHandle(new CreateParams());
        }
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == Constants.WM_HOTKEY_MSG_ID)
            {
                if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == 123)
                {
                    SendKeys.SendWait("^c");
                    string s = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);
                    int tlength = s.Length;
                    char[] ss = s.ToCharArray();
                    if (tlength > 1)
                    {
                        string[] t = new string[tlength];
                        for (int i = 0; i < tlength; i++)
                            t[i] = ss[i].ToString();
                        System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(EnToFa(t), TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);
                    }                        
                }
                if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == 234)
                {
                    SendKeys.SendWait("^c");
                    string s = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);
                    int tlength = s.Length;
                    char[] ss = s.ToCharArray();
                    if (tlength > 1)
                    {
                        string[] t = new string[tlength];
                        for (int i = 0; i < tlength; i++)
                            t[i] = ss[i].ToString();
                        System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(FaToEn(t), TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);                            
                    }                        
                }                    
            }
            SendKeys.Send("^v");
            base.WndProc(ref m);               
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            DestroyHandle();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Was this created as a console app?

Comment: NO, it is a windows form application as i said in Title.

Comment: Obviously, for whatever reason, kit can't find the message pump. However, I note you're using SendWait as it tells you to, in only 2 of three places. Also, the third place, where you're still using SendKeys, looks like it will send ^v for every message received which doesn't look reasonable.

Comment: i have confused with this, I'm working on it about one week but it seems doesn't want to be completed.can you do me a favor to see my hole app, it has some bugs and i don't know how to fix them, if yes, please give me your email to sending you my project.

Comment: Sorry, nope. Unless you want to pay me.

Comment: i want but it doesn't possible, my country is under sanction, so i can't pay you anything. thanks anyway

Comment: can you answer this question: why every time only one of condition in my code is accepted, my mean is it doesn't make difference if keys alt+shift+E or alt+shift+E pressed just the first one and the second one doesn't work and also reverse.

Comment: Not enough info, I'm afraid. Also to have any idea what's going on we'd need to know how this class gets created which you haven't shown, and how whatever creates this class is created. Also, when you say "doesn't work" you need to give a few more details. Similarly, if it throws exceptions, you need to give the exception message and stack trace. Get all that together and ask another question. Also, put C# and win forms tags on it. Good luck -

Comment: more explaining and other code added.

Comment: why you need to call the native functions in your case? you cannot make something for example to activate the second application and apply SendKeys.Send ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the following

1- activate your another application that is running in background

you might find this link helpful [FindWindow and SetForegroundWindow alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512373/findwindow-and-setforegroundwindow-alternatives)

2- apply the sendKeys

```
SendKeys.Send("^(V)");
```

3- reactivate your main appliction

hope this will help you

Comment: it is the correct way bu i don't know enough to do that, need some more help