# How to press a key using voice recognition in C#

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I want to make a program that press a keyboard letter when I say it

```
  namespace LOL
  {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Choices list = new Choices();
    SpeechSynthesizer ss = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    PromptBuilder pb = new PromptBuilder();
    SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list.Add(new string[] { "q", "w", "e" });
        Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(list));
        try
        {
            sre.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
            sre.LoadGrammar(gr);
            sre.SpeechRecognized += Sre_SpeechRecognized;
            sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void Sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Result.Text.ToString())
        {

            case "q":
                SendKeys.Send("q");
            break;

            case "w":
                SendKeys.Send("w");
                break;

            case "e":
                SendKeys.Send("e");
                break;


            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

If I open notepad and say q, w, r it works but if I open other program when let's say if you press q you win something it doesn't work. How I use it? I open the visual, ran the app and after I open the other app, a game. And doesn't work.
I think the problem should be at SendKeys but I don't know how to solve it :\
Any kind of help please?

Comment: *"... if I open other program..."* - What other program?  Does that program have specific functionality to support pressing q/w/e?  What do you expect to happen?  Is it a focus issue?  Can you give your application priority to 'focus' the other app, as a fix?

Comment: @gravity It's called League of Legends a moba where you have some spells and if you press q activate first spell and I would like to activate the q spell when I spell it. I don't know anything about priority, I don't know how should I prioritize my game :\

Comment: You can't, the key is intercepted by the currently running program. See if you can use some of the Functional keys or a combination of keys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use sendkey.send method in my C# windows form application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928820/how-to-use-sendkey-send-method-in-my-c-sharp-windows-form-application)

Comment: You need to bring other window to foreground

Comment: Maybe a Service might work https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/07/creating-windows-services-in-net-core-part-3-the-net-core-worker-way/

Answer (score 0):

Definitely missing the SendWait attribute to the send keys  as well as the curly brackets on your lettering should look like

SendKeys.SendWait("{q}");
also sapi does not implement phonetic alphabet selection so you choices must be spelled how the letter sounds  so (q) would actually be (cue),(w) would be spelled as 
"double you" or something more along these lines