# how to send Ctrl + G to another application?

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts, sendkeys, ctrl, inputsimulator

I'm trying to send CTRL + G keys using InputSimulator with ForegroundWindow but it doesn't work. With other keys it works as expected, for example Ctrl + A or Ctrl + C

[hotkeys menu options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRYcs.png)

I have tried with:

```
Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
if (p != null && p.Length > 0)
{
    IntPtr h = p[0].MainWindowHandle;
    SetForegroundWindow(h);
    InputSimulator sim = new InputSimulator();
    sim.Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke (VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.VK_G) .Sleep (300);
 }
```

or

```
 Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
 if (p != null && p.Length > 0)
 {
    IntPtr h = p[0].MainWindowHandle;
    SetForegroundWindow(h);
    InputSimulator sim = new InputSimulator();
    sim.Keyboard.KeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL);
    sim.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_G).Sleep(300);
    sim.Keyboard.KeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL).Sleep(300);
}
```

Also try:

```
SendKeys.Send ("^ (g)");
```

I have even tried keybd_event (user32.dll function)

Comment: Are you using this [InputSimulator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/InputSimulator)? Is your other application the active window when your code is executed?

Comment: thanks for answering

In effect the active window is the target application, in fact if I use Ctrl-A for example, it works as expected ...

Comment: how do you know it's not being sent?  maybe the target app is ignoring it.

Comment: Hi, you're right ... but when I send Ctrl-A the open window opens correctly. However, Ctrl-G does not open the save window. I have tried other applications, different from notepad and the same thing happens :( ..Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to force the other window into focus before sending the keystrokes. The Microsoft docs have examples detailing this process - [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-simulate-mouse-and-keyboard-events-in-code#to-send-a-keystroke-to-a-different-application)

In short, they use `FindWindow` followed by `SetForegroundWindow`, then send the keys via `SendKeys.SendWait()`, though you can optionally use `SendKeys.Send()`

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12758966/4677797) seems like a concise implementation of the `FindWindow` + `SetForegroundWindow` process.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer ... My initial approach was incomplete ... my problem is only with the Ctrl + G ... Thank you very much